# When I try to delete a div element in a modal dialog the dialog closes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I have a code in which I add and remove divs with dynamic structure in a modal dialog. Strangely, when I try to delete a div element with the remove() method, the modal dialog also closes. But I don't have any code to trigger its shutdown. I can't find the source of the problem.

***This div is before opening the Modal dialog with jquery; (Original state on HTML page);***

```
<div class="modal fade" id="locigModalStep1"  role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
```

***After open model dialog with ".modal('show');"***

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="locigModalStep1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-modal="true" style="display: block;">
```

***After deleting a div element in a modal dialog with the .remove() method;***

```
<div class="modal fade" id="locigModalStep1"  role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
```

***From the link below, you can see the comparison of the html codes before and after deleting the div element;*** [Click Here](https://www.diffchecker.com/6YuM81nJ/)

***When I run the code on stackoverflow, everything seems fine. The delete button works as it should and the dialog does not close. There must be something breaking this build in my own original project.***

```js
function deleteLogicTableButtonFunc(event) {

  const tableId = this.id.replace('deleteTable', '');

  const table = document.getElementById(`tableComponentHeader${tableId}`);
  const operatorContainer = document.getElementById(`logicOperatorContainer${tableId}`);

  table.remove();
  operatorContainer.remove();

}

function addChildToLogicTable(componentId){

            const tableChild = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
            if (tableChild != null) {

              $(tableChild).append(getLinesForAddLogicTable(addLogicComponentTableText, componentId));
                $(tableChild).append(addLogicOperatorButton(componentId));

              const deleteTableButton = document.getElementById("deleteTable"+componentId.toString());
              deleteTableButton.addEventListener("click", deleteLogicTableButtonFunc);

                      
            }

}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

function getLinesForAddLogicTable(func, compId) {

  var myhtml = func.toString();
  var htmlstart = myhtml.indexOf('/*');
  var htmlend = myhtml.lastIndexOf('*/');

  myhtml = myhtml.substr(htmlstart + 2, htmlend - htmlstart - 2);

  myhtml = replaceAll(myhtml, "{selectedComponent}", compId)

  return myhtml;
}


function addLogicComponentTableText() {/*

 <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 20px;" id="tableComponentHeader{selectedComponent}">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteTable{selectedComponent}">Delete</button></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="columnCompName{selectedComponent}">Component Name</th>
            <th>Grup Adresses</th>
            <th>Operator</th>
            <th>Input Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>1. Group Adress: </td>
             <td id="cellGa{selectedComponent}"> --- </td>
             <td>
                 <select class="form-control" id="cellOperatorSelect{selectedComponent}">
                     <option value="equal" selected>==</option>
                     <option value="exclamation">!!</option>
                     <option value="bigger">></option>
                     <option value="smaller"><</option>
                     <option value="biggerAndEqual">>=</option>
                     <option value="smallerAndEqual"><=</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
             <td id="cellInputValue{selectedComponent}">Input</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>2. Group Adress: </td>
             <td id="cellSecondGa{selectedComponent}"> --- </td>
             <td>
                 <select class="form-control" id="cellOperatorSelectSecond{selectedComponent}">
                     <option value="equal" selected>==</option>
                     <option value="exclamation">!!</option>
                     <option value="bigger">></option>
                     <option value="smaller"><</option>
                     <option value="biggerAndEqual">>=</option>
                     <option value="smallerAndEqual"><=</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
             <td id="cellInputValueSecond{selectedComponent}">Input</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Feedback Group Adress: </td>
             <td id="cellFa{selectedComponent}"> --- </td>
             <td>
                 <select class="form-control" id="cellOperatorSelectFeedback{selectedComponent}">
                     <option value="equal" selected>==</option>
                     <option value="exclamation">!!</option>
                     <option value="bigger">></option>
                     <option value="smaller"><</option>
                     <option value="biggerAndEqual">>=</option>
                     <option value="smallerAndEqual"><=</option>
                 </select>
             </td>
             <td id="cellInputValueFeedback{selectedComponent}">Input</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>


*/}

function addLogicOperatorButton(componentId) {
    return `
    <div class="logic-operator-container" id="logicOperatorContainer${componentId}">
        <button class="btn logic-operator logic-operator-selected  btn-success" data-operator="AND">AND</button>
        <button class="btn logic-operator" data-operator="OR">OR</button>
    </div>
    `;
}

$("#addInputComponent").click(function () {

addChildToLogicTable("1");
document.getElementById("addInputComponent").style.visibility = 'hidden';
});

$("#addKnxComponent").click(function () {

addChildToLogicTable("2");
document.getElementById("addKnxComponent").style.visibility = 'hidden';

});

$("#addOutputComponent").click(function () {

addChildToLogicTable("3");
document.getElementById("addOutputComponent").style.visibility = 'hidden';

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="openModalDialog">Open Modal Dialog</button>

<!-- Logic Func Modal Step 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="locigModalStep1"  role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <!-- Modal İçerik -->
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Component Choose</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
  
          <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
            <figure>
              <figcaption style="text-align: center;">Add KNX Component</figcaption>
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img id="addKnxComponent"
                     src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=512&id=24717&format=png"
                     style="max-width: 45px; max-height: 45px; cursor: pointer;" />
              </div>
            </figure>
  
            <figure>
              <figcaption style="text-align: center;">Add INPUT Component</figcaption>
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img id="addInputComponent"
                     src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=512&id=24717&format=png"
                     style="max-width: 45px; max-height: 45px; cursor: pointer;" />
              </div>
            </figure>
  
            <figure>
              <figcaption style="text-align: center;">Add OUTPUT Component</figcaption>
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img id="addOutputComponent"
                     src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=512&id=24717&format=png"
                     style="max-width: 45px; max-height: 45px; cursor: pointer;" />
              </div>
            </figure>
          </div>
  
  
  
          <!-- Tablolar -->
          <div id="tableContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="logicStep1Close">Kapat</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="logicStep1Next">İleri</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $("#openModalDialog").click(function () {
        $('#locigModalStep1').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I edited my question again using the method you said. Strangely, when I run my code here, the delete button behaves as it should and the modal dialog does not close. I guess I'll have to look for what triggered it in my own original project. @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was due to the bootstrap version; I was using the 5.2.1 version in my project, when I downgraded this version to 5.0.2, my problem was solved.

**The version in my project;**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

**The version that solved my problem;**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```